# I want to show panchanga(thithi,day,nakshatra,yoga and karana) details by selecting calendar date

Tags: android, date, onclick, calendar

I am developing Hindu calendar app. I want to show panchanga(thithi,day,nakshatra,yoga and karana) details by selecting calendar date.
How to display panchanga details on choosing calendar date in android application?
Thanks

Comment: what is `panchanga details`? Can you give an example?  Is it some special type of data, which can't be shown with images or text?

Comment: you can do it with database.

Comment: @divya you need to first find out some API which provides you the panchang details for given date.

Comment: @divya [check out this panchang api](http://panchang.click/panchang-api)

Comment: @Jack Jay :I have the api. And i don't know how to use in my project, I am very new to android. I hard coded some text views temporarily and i want to set the textviews accordingly. Can you suggest how to implement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko :Panchangam is the Hindu calendar signified in the Indian Vedic astrology.

Comment: ok, and what is a problem for you to show it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how to use api to display the data.

Comment: which API are you talking about?

Comment: You need to first study the API and then use a network call to the api with paramters like todays date, from its response you can populate your UI.